# Is it possible to do an `$unwind` and a `$sort` on the same array in a way that's supported by an index?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use the aggregation framework to unwind an array and get the results sorted by a field of the subdocument in the array. Is there a way to do this such that an index can be used for the sort?

For example, suppose I have a database of documents like this:

```js
{
  name: "Alan",
  attempts: [{
    assessmentName: "Test 1",
    score: 87
  }, {
    assessmentName: "Test 2",
    score: 62
  }]
}
```

and an index on the scores, `{'attempts.score': 1}`.

I want an aggregation pipeline that results in:

```js
{ name: "Alan", attempts: {assessmentName: "Test 2", score: 62} }
{ name: "Alan", attempts: {assessmentName: "Test 1", score: 87} }
...
```

If I put the `$sort` stage first:

```js
db.students.aggregate([
  {$sort: {'attempts.score': 1}},
  {$unwind: '$attempts'}
])
```

then my index can be used, but the result of course isn't actually sorted after the `$unwind`.

If I put the `$sort` stage second:

```js
db.students.aggregate([
  {$unwind: '$attempts'},
  {$sort: {'attempts.score': 1}}
])
```

then I would get the results I want, but it's not feasible for a large collection because my index can't be used. (Mongo aborts with "Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in." Allowing it to use the disk would avoid that error but wouldn't meet my performance requirements.)

Based on my research so far, my suspicion is that this isn't currently possible with the aggregation framework. But of course I'm hoping I'm wrong.

An update to address some of the comments:
Certainly this challenge could be avoided by changing the data model, but let's assume for the sake of this question that this is the data model we're stuck with. (There are many situations where changing the data model isn't a viable solution, at least not in the short term.)

Also, part of why I asked this question is because I think this is something that Mongo could theoretically support with its existing data structures. For example, if the `$unwind` step accepted a `sortBy` option, then it could use the multikey index to do the unwind in the desired order.

Comment: I do sort of have a workaround, which is to query all distinct scores, sort those in memory in my application, then query sets of those in batches. If nobody can offer a better solution, I'll eventually add an answer with the details of that workaround.

Comment: If all you want as results is the "unwound" content from the arrays in the documents then it's probably a good indicator that the data should not have been embedded in the first place, and therefore should have been put in a different collection. You get around this of course by passing in the `allowDiskUse` option, just like the error is telling you. But there is nothing that can make an index get used beyond the very first pipeline stage. Perhaps you should explain your purpose and why you think you need to return "all the unwound results" in the first place.

Comment: If you want to avoid in-memory sorts you need to adjust your data model to suit your use case. I'd suggest changing your approach so that you have a single `attempt` per document and a supporting index including `score`. Alternatively you could store `attempts` in sorted order (by pushing to a sorted array), but arrays with unbounded growth are a performance anti-pattern. Some elaboration on your use case would be helpful: could there be 100s or 1000s of `attempts` per document? Are you doing any further processing after retrieving the sorted list of scores?

Comment: I've updated the question to address the comments about changing the data structure. Also, the number of `attempts` is usually fewer than 5, but ideally the answer would be the same no matter how large the array.

Comment: @NeilLunn If you create another collection, isn't there the thing that when using mongo its good to avoid lookups, and embed the documents in an array when having 1-Many relation? Lets say that array with the parent document is accessed together, shouldnt be stored together? We have to create another collection only for the sort? It seems to me all the philosophy of mongodb breaks because of sorting. What do you reckon on this matter?